# Swift - NSURL fileURLWithPath not unwrapped?

Tags: swift, nsurl, option-type

Pretty simple one: I'm getting `"Value of optional type 'NSURL?' not unwrapped."` on these two lines, which I'm trying to translate from one of my existing Objective-C apps:

```
func urlForScene(sceneID:Scene) -> NSURL {
    var filename:NSString = "Whatever"
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(filename, ofType: "m4a")
    return NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)
}
```

I assume this is probably something blindingly simple to do with the possibility of the `path` being nil, but I've not found any other questions which let me know what I should be doing here. Apologies if it's a stupid question.

If the `NSURL` isn't unwrapped, should I unwrap it? Do I need to call `fileURLWithPath:` differently?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide some context ? What's the return type of the function you're in ?

Comment: @DCMaxxx I've updated the question with the full method, hopefully that helps.

Comment: Note that you can do it in one step instead of two, using `URLForResource(..., withExtension: ...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the issue : `urlForScene` returns a `NSURL`, whereas `fileURLWithPath:` returns an optional : `NSURL?`, (as per the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/fileURLWithPath:)).

So, the issue is, `fileURLWithPath:` might return `nil` (this is why it returns a `NSURL?`), and you return a non-nil object (a `NSURL`).

The compiler tells you to unwrap it, but I'd say you'd better return a `NSURL?` and check it later on in your code.

Plus, you shouldn't use `NSObject.someInitializer(anObject)`, but `NSObject(initializer:anObject)`. In your case, replace `NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)`by `NSURL(fileURLWithPath:path)`.

To summarize, here's the working code :

```
func urlForScene(sceneID:Scene) -> NSURL? {
    let filename = "Whatever"

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(filename, ofType: "m4a")
    if let path = path {
        return NSURL(fileURLWithPath:path)
    } else {
        return nil
    }

/* this would also work, it's a matter of taste :
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(filename, ofType: "m4a") {
    return NSURL(fileURLWithPath:path)
}
return nil
*/

} 

let mySceneURL = urlForScene(someScene)
if let mySceneURL = mySceneURL {
    /* use the scene */
} else {
    /* the scene couldn't be intialized */
}
```

Comment: Nope, it's still complaining. I've literally copied and pasted that function in, and it's complaining "Value of optional type String? not unwrapped" on the return line, complaining about `path`.

Comment: Oops, my bad. There's the same issue with the path (it returns an `NSString?`). I'll update the sample code.

Comment: I confirm, same issue with the path variable. I suggest the OP to read the Swift manual looking for "Optionals"

Comment: The above solution is, IMHO, a bad idea if it is a programmer error for the file to be missing from the bundle. If that is the case, then it would be better for the app to crash in the `urlForScene` method.

Answer (score 2):

`NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)` returns an optional NSURL, as you can see in its declaration.

```
class func fileURLWithPath(path: String) -> NSURL?
```

But your `urlForScene` method returns a non-optional NSURL.
If you are sure that an URL will be returned, you can unwrap it by adding an exclamation mark at the end (alias: unwrapping)

```
return NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)!
```

However, for safety reason, I suggest you to check for nil before returning the value:

```
let returningURL : NSURL? = NSURL.fileURLWithPath("http://www.lombax.it")
if let url = returningURL
{
    return url
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: That hasn't worked. I've added the exclamation mark (`return NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)!`) and it's giving the exact same error.

Comment: Are you sure you have pasted all your code? If the declaration of `urlForScene` is correct (it returns a non-optional NSURL) then adding a ! MUST work.

Comment: For example, this works
    func testMe() -> NSURL
    {
        return NSURL.fileURLWithPath("http://www.lombax.it")!
    }

Comment: reading the other post I confirm that you have the same problem with the "path" variable. I suggest you to look at the Swift manual at the Optionals chapter.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer depends on a couple of things you don't mention.

Do you know that the file will exist in the bundle then:

```
func urlForScene(sceneID:Scene) -> NSURL {
    var filename = "Whatever"
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(filename, ofType: "m4a")
    return NSURL(fileURLWithPath:path!)!
}
```

If you aren't sure whether the file will exist in the bundle, then it would be better to pass back an optional:

```
func urlForScene(sceneID:Scene) -> NSURL? {
    var result: NSURL?
    var filename = "Whatever"
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(filename, ofType: "m4a") {
        result = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:path)
    }
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By having a return type of NSURL you state that the method MUST under all circumstances return an NSURL. The only alternative for the method is to crash.

That's quite easy to achieve by returning NSURL (...)! with an exclamation mark. Your code will return an NSURL, or it will crash. If that's what you want... Or if you are absolutely, one hundred percent sure, that fileURLWithPath cannot fail.

Answer (score 1):

If your file is local and there is no chance of it ever being nil, go to Targets > Build Phases and make sure it is added to Copy Bundle Resources.