# Cannot invoke 'split' with an argument list of type '(String, (String) -> Bool)' in SWIFT 2

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

The error: Cannot invoke 'split' with an argument list of type '(String, (String) -> Bool)'

Code i want to use: `let nameArr = split(name) {$0 == "."}`

Comment: Have a look at (the Swift 2 updates to) http://stackoverflow.com/a/25229901/1187415.

Answer (score 4):

**Strings are No Longer Collections**, `String` no longer conforms to `CollectionType`. You can use other alternatives like the function [`componentsSeparatedByString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString:):

```
var name = "Victor.Hello.GYTT" 
let nameArr = name.componentsSeparatedByString(".") // [Victor, Hello, GYTT]
```

Another option is using the `characters` property:

```
let nameArr = split(name.characters) { $0 == "." }.map { String($0) }
```

With the new `.init` syntax in Xcode 7 beta 2, where `init` "can now be referenced like static methods" like in the following way:

```
let nameArr = split(name.characters) { $0 == "." }.map { String.init }
```

Or making the `String` conforms the protocol too, but Apple made a decision to remove `String` conformance to `Sliceable`, be carefull.

You can read more about notables changes in [Changes to the Swift Standard Library in 2.0 beta 1](http://airspeedvelocity.net/2015/06/09/changes-to-the-swift-standard-library-in-2-0-beta-1/) in the blog of @AirSpeedVelocity. Really nice.

I hope this help you.

Comment: am getting an error  Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'NSURL'

Comment: Provide the declaration of your variable `name`, see my answer

Comment: am really new to swift so idk what to do here is the error [Image](http://i.imgur.com/qctEMll.png)

Comment: I saw you error , but what's the problem? you can't use the `split` in this way anymore , you need to change your line `let nameArr = split(name) {$0 == "."}` for any of the above I explained you.

Comment: sorry for being a pain but neither of them worked for me each one shows an error in a different way like for example look at this [image](http://i.imgur.com/yhI1t53.png)

Comment: @OmarShiltawi You're experimented another error different from what you posted, you need  to do this NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)! , you can read more about it in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27214814/swift-nsurl-fileurlwithpath-not-unwrapped)